# Keyboard typing random forward slashes by itself

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard

I just bought a ACER ASPIRE V3-572G laptop that came with a preinstalled Windows 8.1, booted it up, set up the OS, installed virtually nothing and then started getting some Windows updates. Got a bunch of them, then some bigger one (~770MB - KB3000850) started failing because something was locking up the files.

I deleted the McAfee LiveSafe that came with it and it installed the update just fine. Restarted the thing and weird stuff started happening, couldnt enter my password because some characters were being automatically typed into the text box, finally got in, system was behaving kinda weird, sort of being interrupted and when typing into browser address bar I noticed that forward slashes are being typed by themselves, opened up a text editor and so it was. '////////' everywhere. Thats the story.

I am pretty sure the key is not stuck, I barely touched the keyboard and it was in my line of sight all the time so nothing was spilled or anything, plus the forward slashes come at random, sometimes not at all, sometimes its like ticks, sometimes as if the key was pressed down.
Should I start rolling back windows updates, cause I did some typing during the setup phase and didnt have this type of problem. Any way to track down what is causing it? Don`t really want to factory reset and then have the same thing all over again.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Press all the keys on the keyboard, then reboot, hit Del, to get into the UEFI, which some will allow renaming things, and test it there. (the lowest level). get into a "command prompt only" type of mode or "safe modes" and test it there. It comming in "random" could be due only to the keyboard buffer filling up.

Comment: Hello, just did that and the same thing is happening in UEFI, that meaning what?

Comment: It sounds like a key is stuck, which doesn't actually have to be a key, but a connection is made in the keyboard electronics, the grid, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound like a problem you want to mess with. Just exchange it for one that works before warranty is up.

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what I did, turned out to be a hardware issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem!